# NTLM Login using PHP and Apache

Tags: php, windows, apache, ntlm

I would like to login into my system using ntlm protocol. I found module for apache - mod_auth_sspi, but i need multi platform solution.

My application have to run on windows and linux (on both is installed php>=5.3 and apache>2.0).
Using mod_auth_sspi i am able to login via ntlm, but only if I set a:

required user-valid

in htaccess or http.conf. 
If I don't set this value I can't retrieve USER_REMOTE and I don't know how can I implement solution that I need:

I'm looking for solution that allow me show to user form with login/password (ntlm) or if user cancelled this form the system should redirect him to alternative login form (data will retrieve from database). I need to login into the system in 2 ways: via NTLM and traditional (database). How Can I do this?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mod_auth_sspi for windows, and http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/ for linux. I know it isn't the best solution, but it should work (i guess you will have to check what OS the script is running on and choose the mod appropriately since I doubt the APIs are the same).

EDIT:

For multiple login providers, see this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/howto/auth.html#multprovider

Comment: OK, but second problem? How can I connect NTLM login window and my own login window. If User clicked "Cancel" in NTLM window then the system have to redirect him to alternative login form, is it possible? Becouse now I set NTLM option in http.conf and inside this file I set "required user-valid" (which occurs that user always see ntlm form (even after cancel or refresh).

Comment: Yes, but I need multiple login providers which are NTLM (in windows SSPI) and www-login i.e. Symfony sfGuard in the same domain. So my system should check apache authentication (SSPI) and then (alternative way) should redirect to page in the same domain. So, When user enter my page first time he should see apache authentication, but if he click "cancel" or he wrote wrong password he shall redirect to other page in the same domain and system should show him a new form - symfony+sfGuard. THIS IS MY REAL PROBLEM ;-)

Comment: Ah, got it. You can try changing the 401 unauthorized page to redirect to Symfony. It is a bit hacky, but thats the only way I see it working.

Comment: Done ;-)

I Created two Virtual Hosts in Apache. One is dedicated for NTLM authentication, and another one is for normal login (by symfony form).
So, User can choose which application he wants (after entering correct address into address bar in his browser).

Answer (score -1):

I know old question but might be useful for future users landing here from Google. A cross-platform (I have it running on Windows and Ubuntu) solution would be PyAuthenNTLM2:

https://github.com/Legrandin/PyAuthenNTLM2

An important additional advantage of this module compared to others is that it supports NTLM version 2 (NTLMv2) protocol which is a bit more "secure". It is important that Windows 7 (and AFAIK Vista too) use NTLMv2 only per default (it can be switched in registry) and hence you won't force the windows admins in your company to change this setting.

Comment: That is a Python library. We're looking for PHP.

Comment: It a module for apache web server and hence can be used with PHP. In fact that's exactly what I'm doing. (Note: Without fix only works for apache 2.2 and not 2.4) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736544/apache2-php-create-automatic-ntlm-login-page